# How do I parse an ISO 8601/RFC 3339 timezone with NSDateFormatter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, rfc3339

I have a date string like this ([ISO 8601 combined date and time representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) or RFC 3339):

> 2010-09-04T19:13:00Z

But how do I configure the NSDateFormatter to accept this timezone format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html) about what Apple recommends:

```
// Convert the RFC 3339 date time string to an NSDate.

NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

[rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDate *date = [rfc3339DateFormatter dateFromString:rfc3339DateTimeString];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:'2010-09-04T19:13:00Z'];
```